# C# Dynamics 365: Set lookup value to null or blank

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 I have an employee (user) that has a reference to his/her manager (another user). I want to programatically clear that value.

This line of code will update to any user that matches the ID. But I am not able to clear the value.

```
user.Attributes["parentsystemuserid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", managerId);
service.Update(user);
```

I have tried things like setting the `managerId` value to "null", "", and a Guid consisting only of zeroes. I am not able to find many attempts to answers to this online. This here http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/2007/02/set-lookup-to-null.html was my best bet, but as far as I can tell "Entity" does not hold a "Lookup" property, so no luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
user.Attributes["parentsystemuserid"] = null;
service.Update(user);
```

Comment: Thank you it does. I am sure I tried that as the first thing.